# How to post a hidden jQuery DataTables column to a form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, post, datatables

I have a DataTable with some visible columns (first name, last name) and one hidden column (id). I'm using the DataTable row select example to highlight the row that the user selects. When a button is pressed I am able to display the value in the hidden column for the selected row. What I'm trying to figure out is how to post that hidden value to another page as an input variable on my form.

Here's the function that my button calls, which simply displays the hidden id column that I want to post.

```
$('#select').click( function() {

   var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );

   if ( anSelected.length == 0 ) {
      alert('Please make a selection');
   } else {

      // Get data from the selected row                    
      var aRow = anSelected[0];
      var sFirstName = oTable.fnGetData( aRow, 0 );
      var sLastName = oTable.fnGetData( aRow, 1 );
      var sID = oTable.fnGetData( aRow, 2 );

      alert('You have selected ' + sID);
   }
} );
```

I am unclear as to how to post this value as an input variable on a form.

I also found an example that attempts to address this but it fails to show how to actually post the value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var oTable;

   $('#form').submit( function() {
      var sData = $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();
      alert( "The following would have been submitted to the form: \n\n"+sData );
      return true;
   } );

   oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

} );
```

I'm new to jQuery and DataTables, in case you hadn't guessed. :)

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Does this help http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ ?

Comment: So, where did you stop? What happens? Can you alert the `selectedId` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with two different solutions to this problem, which I'm posting for others who may find them useful.  The basic idea is:

(a) know which row the user has selected 
(b) read the value of the hidden column for that row 
(c) assign the value to a hidden form field

The difference between the two solutions is when the value is assigned.  In the first solution the value is assigned when the user hits the submit button.  In the second solution the value is assigned every time the user clicks a row.

Solution #1: This builds on my previously posted code.  Here I have simply replaced the alert dialog box with a statement that assigns the hidden value to a hidden form field using the getElementById function.

```
$('#select').click( function() {

   var anSelected = oTable.$('tr.row_selected');

   if ( anSelected.length == 0 ) {
      alert('Please make a selection');
   } else { 
      // Get data from the selected row                    
      var aRow = anSelected[0];
      var sFirstName = oTable.fnGetData( aRow, 0 ); // Don't need this anymore
      var sLastName = oTable.fnGetData( aRow, 1 ); // Don't need this anymore
      var sID = oTable.fnGetData( aRow, 2 ); // Hidden column

      document.getElementById('hiddenUserID').value = sID;
   }
} );
```

In my form I have a hidden input field and a submit button that calls the function above.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="hiddenUserID" value="" />
<button id="select" type="submit">Select User</button>
```

Solution #2: In this solution I am assigning the value every time the user selects a row.  The code borrows from the DataTables row select example, which can be found here:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/select_single_row.html

```
/* Add a click handler to the rows */
$("#example tbody tr").click( function( e ) {

    if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
    } else {
        oTable.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
        $(this).addClass('row_selected');

        // Get the data from the selected row
        var sID = oTable.fnGetData( this, 2 );
        document.getElementById('hiddenUserID').value = sID;
    }
});
```

My form has the same hidden input field as mentioned above.  My submit button also calls the function in the first solution, but only to check that a row has been selected.

Both solutions work great.  I suppose which one you use depends on personal preference and needs.

Comment: what about multiple selected rows from different pages? how would you build the values (IDs) array and post toghether with other fields from a form? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've got basically your same need, here is my take at the solution:

1) Create the dataTable passing a custom `fnCreatedRow` callback. The callback will be used to add a click listener on each created row.

```
var options = {
    fnCreatedRow: createdRow,
    ...
};

var dataTable = element.dataTable(options);
```

2) While creating the listener, make sure to forward the row index to the actual listener

```
function createdRow(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
    $(nRow).on('click', {dataIndex: iDataIndex}, rowClickListener);
}
```

3) In click listener, use the index to get the actual *data* for the row (that is JS object, not HTML), invoking the `fnGetData' API on the dataTable object.

```
function rowClickListener (evt) {
    var rowData = dataTable.fnGetData(evt.data.dataIndex);

    console.log(rowData.lastName + ' ' rowData.firstName);
}
```

Credits for this goes also to user [spasco](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/4199/accessing-hidden-column-data/p1).